# What is the right SE site for Kuali apps related questions?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Under the Kuali suite there are various university enterprise applications including a framework/middleware for development of these applications.  These are created through community efforts as open source.  A collaboration of universities across the globe are developing and implementing them at their institutions.

What would be the best stack exchange site for questions regarding implementation, configuration, and customization of these applications?  Questions will easily overlap topics of such sites like [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) and [webapps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/). I can easily see the questions to be flagged as off-topic in any of these sites and that's why I'm asking.

We started an area 51 proposal for a specific stack exchange site for these questions but reluctantly came to the conclusions that the bars for the site requirements are quite high and not likely for us to meet. This effort did give us a nice list of [sample questions](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/54050/kuali?phase=definition&tab=votes#tab-top) for reference to the kind of questions I'm inquiring about.

Comment: Does your question concern the [server-side setup](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) or the [software itself](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic)?

Comment: Please stop the closing of specific questions as dupes of other tangentially related specific questions.

Comment: @Lance Meta closures often link to broader questions which cover the same information.

Answer (score 1):

It completely depends on which aspect you are asking the question about.

- Programming - [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)
- Server Stuff - [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/)
- Web Use - [WebApps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/)